# pull Vimeo download link in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, api, video, vimeo

I am a Vimeo Pro user and they have an option of downloading my videos. My concern so far is once i publish the video download URL in a membership site and a person distributes it over the web, i have no control over it but to delete the video itself.

I was told i can generate the download URL through the Vimeo API to come up with expiring download links. But when I tried to get a video download URL through the API playground, it seems it expires after a certain period of time. If I go this way, that means I have to replace my video download URL's in my wordpress site every time a URL expired.

Is there a way for me to pull the non-expiring download URL of the video but the users in my Wordpress site see an expiring download link when they click on it - like Amazon S3 download URLs?

If there is, what are the codes needed and where would I place the codes in Wordpress core files like functions.php etc?

Thanks for your help and instructions from the basic steps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give wordpress specific examples, but one way might be to create your own wordpress page that generates the download link, and redirects your user to the download link.

Then you can control access via the wordpress link